# How do I load this dynamic components in Vue 3 composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

Im trying to load a component with the name that I get from the database, but it keeps sending me the error
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.

```
import SimpleQuestions from '@/components/SimpleQuestions.vue';

const templates = {
  SimpleQuestions,
}

const getMissionComponent = async (name) =>{
  let missionInfo = await userStore.getMissionInfo(email.value, roomID.value, name);
  let templateName = missionInfo.template; 
  switch (templateName){
    case 'SimpleQuestions':
      return templates[templateName];

<div v-for="(mission, index) in missions" :key="index">
      <component :is="getMissionComponent(mission)"></component>
    </div>
```

When I put directly in the :is the words SimpleQuestions it detects the component and it loads, but in the function, it does not.
Does anyone have an idea about what is happening?

Comment: You need to either get async data before calling getMissionComponent, or use async component https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async , i.e. getMissionComponent function should synchronously return another function. The latter doesn't look like a good idea at all because it will be fetched on each render if not cached. Conisider reasking the question with your case explained, could be XY problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use async components,you need use defineAsyncComponent to creat it according to  [the vue document](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html)

```js
import SimpleQuestions from '@/components/SimpleQuestions.vue';
import {
  defineAsyncComponent
} from 'vue'

const templates = {
  SimpleQuestions,
}
const getMissionComponent = async(name) => {
  let missionInfo = await userStore.getMissionInfo(email.value, roomID.value, name);
  let templateName = missionInfo.template;
  switch (templateName) {
    case 'SimpleQuestions':
      return templates[templateName];

  }
}

function creatAsyncComponent(prop) {
  return defineAsyncComponent(()=>getMissionComponent(prop))
}

<div v-for = "(mission, index) in missions": key = "index" >
  <component: is = "creatAsyncComponent(mission)" ></component> 
</div>
```